# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n!)^2x^{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n^2}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

This is a question from an exam I recently failed.

What is the radius of convergence of the following power series? $$(a) \sum_{n=1}^\infty(n!)^2x^{n^2}$$ and $$(b) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n^2}}{n!}$$

Edit: Here's my attempt at the first one, if someone could tell me if it's any good...

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n!)^2x^{n^2}$=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ where $a_n= 0$ for any $n\notin \{k\in N| \exists t\in N: k=t^2\}$ and $a_n = (n!)^2$ else. So the radius of convergence would be the inverse of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(n!)^{2/n}}=\lim e^{2/n\cdot log(n!) }$. The exponent with log of factorial becomes a series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{logn}{n}$ which diverges by comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$, so the radius of convergence would be equal to $0$.

Second edit: This is wrong. Correct answer below.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: Consider $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (|a_n|)^{1/(n^2)}$ where $a_n$ are the coefficients.

Comment: According to Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence will be $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{2}{n^2}}$ and not what you wrote (not that at the $n = k^2$ index, the expression is $(k!)^{\frac{2}{k^2}}$ and not $(k!)^{\frac{2}{k}}$).

Comment: @levap Are you sure? And then what?

Comment: @Noa: Well, then you need to compute the limit and show that it is $1$. But this is much harder than using other tests.

Comment: @Noa, if you don't mind me asking, which college is this exam from?

Comment: @MaxisJaisi Tel Aviv University in Israel (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the first series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n!)^2 x^{n^2}$. The easiest way to find the radius of convergence is to forget this is a power series and treat $x$ as a constant. Let's assume $x > 0$ so that the terms of the series are positive and we can use any test we wish for the convergence/divergence of a non-negative series. Alternatively, replace $x$ with $|x|$ and check for absolute convergence instead. Using the ratio test, we get the expression
$$ \frac{(n+1)!^2 x^{(n+1)^2}}{(n!)^2 x^{n^2}} = (n+1)^2 x^{2n + 1}. $$
This expression converges if $0 < x < 1$ to $0$ while it diverges if $x \geq 1$. This implies that the series converges if $0 < x < 1$ and diverges if $x \geq 1$. But this is a power series so the only possible value for the radius of convergence is $R = 1$ (because it should converge when $|x| < R$ and diverge when $|x| > R$).

Comment: If you want to think of the series a power series, then formally you need to define a sequence $a_k$ such that your series has the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x^k$. Then the sequence $a_k$ will be zero if $k \neq n^2$ is not a square and $a_k = (n!)^2$ if $k = n^2$ is a square. Then you can use Cauchy-Hadamard or the ratio test for power series using the $\limsup$ version but this is more complicated.

Comment: this was what I did at the test and this answer was not accepted as there's a zero subsequence for the sequence in the power series, so the expression $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is not always defined...

Comment: Formally, your series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n!)^2 x^{n^2}$ is not even a power series. It can be considered as a power series by adding extra terms which are zeroes and this won't change the convergence or the divergence of the series (an easy theorem). If you consider the original series without extra zeroes as a regular series when $x \neq 0$, it doesn't have any zero terms and the ratio is always defined.

Comment: @Noa: I don't see any geometric series around, but anyway, this is indeed a question that is not suited for Cauchy-Hadamard. The advantage of Cauchy-Hadamard is that the formula **always** gives you the radius of convergence but it doesn't mean you can compute the limit involved easily. If not, then it's better to use all the other tools in your disposal. I went for the ratio test because it looked better to try a quotient then an $n$-th root (more cancellation).

Comment: Yeah, what I wrote was nonsense. Sorry. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the ratio test. The ratio of consecutive terms is of the form $n^p x^{2n-1}$. For $|x|<1$, the $n\to\infty$ limit is $0$; for $|x|>1$, it is $\infty$. Thus the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: This was what I did and got me getting no points for this question, as the sequence of the power series has a zero subsequence.

Comment: @Noa The trick is to define the sequence on which we use the test as the nonzero terms alone, rather than a full power series.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

The ration test gives for $a) $,

$$\lim_\infty (n+1)^2e^{(2n+1)\ln (|x|)}$$
$$=0$$ if $|x|<1$.